# Note creation in Sales Cloud from a cloud page using AMPScript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage, sales-cloud

I want to create NOTE and tag it to existing lead in sales cloud. I have created a cloud page and using ampscript to acheive this. But somehow it is not working.

```
SET @noteCreate = CreateSalesforceObject('ContentDocumentLink', 3, 'title', 'Coming from cloud page', 'Description', 'This is the first note created from Cloud', 'LinkedEntityId', @leadCreate)
```

Please help!!

Comment: “Something is not working” is a quite vague description of your problem. Please be more precise. Also, do include more code than just this single line - as the real problem might be elsewhere

Comment: LukasLunow, apart from this one line, there is another CreateSalesforceObject() call to create a lead and ID of that lead is stored in @leadcreate. but lead creation is working fine. Now i have remove that code and hardcoding the leadid in the above call. So, this is only code in my cloud page.

Answer (score 0):

CreateSFObject and the other cross cloud methods are nasty to debug blindly. Suggestion, wrap it in a try / catch block and put it on a cloudpage to get an error message, these usually help:

using your unchanged code:

```
<script type="javascript" runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core","1");
try {

</script>
%%[
 SET @noteCreate = CreateSalesforceObject('ContentDocumentLink', 3, 'title', 'Coming from cloud page', 'Description', 'This is the first note created from Cloud', 'LinkedEntityId', @leadCreate)

]%%
<script type="javascript" runat="server">
    Write("success");
} catch (err) {
    Write(Stringify(err));

}
</script>
```

typical errors for createSFOBject are listed below - the error message should give you a good indication where to begin.

a) have you included all required fields ? The docs say that "ShareType" is one of them, and you are missing it.
Docs: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdocumentlink.htm

b) Is the number of fields matching with the number of key value pairs you define (in your case, that looks fine)

c) general: do you have the permission as the Marketing Cloud API User? Try to perform the operation via the Sales Cloud UI to verify

d) wrong value formatting (dates, decimals...) - basically, go field by field.

e) duplicate rules (e.g. for leads and contacts)

Hope this helps